# How to configure g++ compiler in netbeans 8.1 correctly for c++11/c++14 support?

Tags: c++, netbeans-8

I'm a novice and work my way through Programming Principles and Practise using c++ by stroustrup ... I'm using Netbeans ide 8.1 and have a problem with the following:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    cout << v[i] << "\n";
}
```

If I compile, I get the error
could not convert `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` from `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `Vector<int>` . I thought this has maybe something to do with missing compiler support for `c++11` or 14, my `compiler` is `g++ 4.8`. Do I have to add anything to the `compiler` settings or is it another problem? Thanks

Comment: use `-std=c++11` in compiler switches, or `-std=c++1y`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the [new](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) version of `"std_lib_facilities.h"` instead of the [old](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the compiler flag -std=c++14 for c++ 14 and likewise -std=c++11 for c++ 11. Only add one of these flags to the build flags in your IDE.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the Headerfile, there is some mistake in it I think. If I delete #include std_lib_facilities.h and include <iostream> <vector> , it works fine.