# Enabling C++14 in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to enable C++14 in Netbeans for both the IDE and the compiler ?

- I can tell the IDE to use C++11 by setting `C++11` in the *C++ Standard* option of the *C++ compiler* category.
- I can tell the compiler to use C++14 by adding `-std=c++14` in the *Additional Options* of the same category.

I see two problems :

- If the IDE is not C++14 compliant, the code assistance could be wrong for uses of compliant C++14 that do not comply with C++11 standard.
- The compiler is given both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` flags. By my tests, I can see that the relevant one is the last one on the command line. Sadly, the IDE puts the *Additional Options* arguments before the *C++ Standard* argument, on the compiler command line.

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2. A consistent solution, if any, avoiding to upgrade to a newer version is preferred. I'm using gcc 4.9.2.

As far as I understand their answers, these related questions do not answer mine :

- [How to configure g++ compiler in netbeans 8.1 correctly for c++11/c++14 support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324934/how-to-configure-g-compiler-in-netbeans-8-1-correctly-for-c11-c14-support)
- [Setting Default NetBeans Options (-std=c99, -Wall) for C programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882981/setting-default-netbeans-options-std-c99-wall-for-c-programs)

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965413/compile-c14-code-with-g - This statement: So up till 4.9.3 you had to use -std=c++1y while the gcc 5.2 options say:

‘c++14’ ‘c++1y’

The 2014 ISO C++ standard plus amendments. The name ‘c++1y’ is deprecated.

Comment: @domenkavran using `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++1y` gives the same value to `__cplusplus`. I've checked the gcc source code, and the answer you linked is not correct. The documentation does not list the `c++14` option value, but the value is nevertheless valid. It was done on purpose according to https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-03/msg00343.html

Answer (score 1):

No way has been found. We switched to Netbeans 8.2 which has support for C++14.